# Why does ConfigureAwait(false) called from the UI thread works on a XAML bound property for UI updates?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, async-await

In my code behind, I have an button click event handler to do some IO work with `ConfigureAwait(false)` suffixed to the Task.

Now I would expect when the `async` task is completed, it would not resume on the UI thread. So, `TxtStatus.Text` assignment is expected to fail and it did.

Question is, if this TextBox is bound using a Model that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` then it works and the UI is updated.

Why is that possible, shouldn't the UI update fail as well?

The following code snippets are my current code with sufficient details to establish the context of my question.

View

```
<TextBox Name="TxtStatus" Text="{Binding Model.Status, Mode=TwoWay}/>
```

View's CodeBehind

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{        
    await _viewModel.DoWorkAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

    //TxtStatus.Text = "This does not work.";

    _viewModel.Model.Status= "This works.";            
}
```

Model

```
public class MyModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _status;
    public string Status
    {
        get => _status;
        set 
        { 
            _status= value; 
            OnPropertyChanged(); 
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Data bound properties can be changed from non-UI threads; WPF handles it automatically.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994714/updating-bound-properties-from-a-background-thread

Comment: `INotifyProertyChanged.PropertyChanged` is marshalled to execute on the UI thread.